# merging dataframes on the same index

Tags: python, pandas

I can't find the answer to this in here. 
I have two dataframes:

```
index,  name,   color, day
   0    Nan     Nan    Nan
   1    b       red    thu
   2    Nan     Nan    Nan
   3    d       green  mon

index,  name,  color,   week
    0    c      blue    1
    1    Nan    Nan     Nan
    2    t      yellow  4
    3    Nan    Nan     Nan
```

And I'd like the result to be one dataframe:

```
index,  name,   color,  day,   week  
    0       c   Blue    Nan    1
    1       b   red     thu    Nan
    2       t   yellow  Nan    4
    3       d   green   mon    Nan
```

**Is there a way to merge the dataframes on their indexes, while adding new columns?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2)
print (df)
    color  day name  week
0    blue  NaN    c   1.0
1     red  thu    b   NaN
2  yellow  NaN    t   4.0
3   green  mon    d   NaN
```

For custom order of columns create columns names by [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), [`pd.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.unique.html) and then add [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
cols = pd.unique(np.concatenate([df1.columns, df2.columns]))
df = df1.combine_first(df2).reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
  name   color  day  week
0    c    blue  NaN   1.0
1    b     red  thu   NaN
2    t  yellow  NaN   4.0
3    d   green  mon   NaN
```

EDIT:

Use rename columns:

```
df = df1.combine_first(df2.rename(columns={'week':'day'}))
print (df)
  name   color  day
0    c    blue    1
1    b     red  thu
2    t  yellow    4
3    d   green  mon
```

Comment: @jezrale What if I wanted to add the week values under the day column so the column day would end up like this: day[1,thu,4,mon]. Is this also possible?

Comment: I think simpliest is rename column, give me a sec.